# How to send verification link via google app engine

Tags: email, google-app-engine

I'm trying to send a link for verification code: but for some reson it won't send it. when i add http://dddd-dogi-1234 .appspot.com/verifier?vc=' space between them its working but the link is divided by 2..:/

```
  url = str('http://' + APP_NAME + '/verifier?vc=' + v_code)

message = \
    mail.EmailMessage(sender='daniel fisher <yad4project@gmail.com>'
                      , subject='Verification Confirm'
                      )

message.to = 'Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>'
st = 'http://dddd-dogi-1234.appspot.com/verifier?vc='
msg = \
    """ Dear User:
        In Order to Register 'yad 4' app you must first confirm youe email address
        please visit %s and add the verification number on screen to the app

        Good luck!
                                                                        The yad4 project Team""" %st



message.body =  msg
message.send()
```

any idea why? and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide more details? It's not really clear what you mean by email is not being sent unless you divide the link into two parts... When you add the space into the link - the email is delivered but when you don't - the email isn't delivered? Any errors / logs?

Comment: it means that gAE probably won't let me send an appspot domain inside. so i devided the link, so it can be sent out

Comment: Are you getting any errors when sending it properly? Could it be your spam filter?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is most likely this open GAE issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12786.

As a workaround try to survive with the link broken in 2 for now. Star the issue and you'll get status updates by emails, so that you can fix the broken link when the GAE issue is fixed.

Or, if the email volume is tolerable, send the emails to yourself then fix the link and re-send them to the final recipient manually until the issue is fixed.